# Is there a way to disable the debug logo banner in Flutter through Android Studio?

Tags: flutter

Why I am not be able to remove the debug logo banner from my flutter app??
please help me to fix this problem.In android stdio the option is there to remove that banner but in
android stdio flamingo this option is not showing why??
In android stduio flutter inspector is not showing any options to remove the debug logo banner.

Answer (score 1):

Simply adding

```
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
```

to your MaterialApp widget is enough.